# Use of the magic function %matplotlib inline

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I tried to see the difference between using **%matplotlib inline** and without this statement. But there is no difference between two output. Then **what is its use ?**

Output without **%matplotlib inline** line:
[image]

Output with **%matplotlib inline**:
[image]

Comment: I have gone through the [documentation] http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html) but it is not clear to me.

Comment: Your jupyter may be configured in a way to use `%matplotlib inline` by default, hence you do not see a difference.

Comment: How can I see that? I want to see the difference.

Comment: You would see the difference by choosing another backend. E.g.`%matplotlib notebook` or `%matplotlib tk`.

Comment: Ok  "%matplotlib notebook " worked