# Is %matplot inline obsolete?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Based on my understanding from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43027980/purpose-of-matplotlib-inline) `%matplotlib inline` is used so figures can be shown in Jupyter. But figures are shown in Jupyter without using `%matplotlib inline` perfectly fine. for example the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.random.randn(50).cumsum())
plt.show()
```

So is `%matplotlib inline` obsolete or am I misunderstanding it's purpose?

Comment: Till date there seems to be no answer to this mystery. Check this unanswered question of mine from over an year ago: [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329901/behavior-of-matplotlib-inline-plots-in-jupyter-notebook-based-on-the-cell-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329901/behavior-of-matplotlib-inline-plots-in-jupyter-notebook-based-on-the-cell-conten)

Comment: I'm not sure I would call it obsolete, but rather the default.  If you run `print(plt.get_backend())` you'll see it is `ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline` right from the start.  If you switch to some other backend you can use that magic to switch back.

Comment: @jayveesea I think you should submit your comment as an answer as it answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default matplotlib [backend](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#backends) in a jupyter notebook is `inline`.  You can inspect this by using `print(plt.get_backend())` after loading matplotlib.  For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
print(plt.get_backend())
```

returns `module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline`

The magic `%matplotlib` can be used to switch back to `inline` if you had switched to some other backend.  The following cells can illustrate this when run in a notebook.

In [100]:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.random.randn(50).cumsum())
```

In [101]:

```py
%matplotlib notebook
plt.plot(np.random.randn(50).cumsum())
```

In [103]:

```py
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(np.random.randn(50).cumsum())
```