# Question regarding jupyter notebook inline magic

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, inline

I was looking at a few tutorials about plotting inline with jupyter notebook and they all say to use the %matplotlib inline, but when I run code normally from my notebook and call plot.show() the chart shows automatically without using magic. I'm am running jupyter from the anaconda package so not sure if that makes a difference.

Is it still necessary to use the inline magic for matplotlib?

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54329901/behavior-of-matplotlib-inline-plots-in-jupyter-notebook-based-on-the-cell-conten) quite a while ago but did not get any answer yet. You can also see a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50992742/use-of-the-magic-function-matplotlib-inline)

Answer (score 0):

The point of that particular magic is to avoid the need for `plt.show()`, and show the plot directly on `plt.plot(...)`.

If you don't mind using `.show()`, you don't need `%matplotlib inline`. I think it's more convenient to use it.

Comment: I disagree. Read the **Case 1** in my first linked post in the comment above. In JuPyTer notebook, the plots appear even without using `%matplotlib inline` and `plt.show()`

Comment: Maybe we're running some different configurations or something, but your case 1 isn't working the same way on my end. Maybe you alreasy set the default backend to be inline (like in ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer)?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple: If the inline backend is selected by default, there is no need to activate it again.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `%matplotlib inline`, the Jupyter notebook will save the graph to the notebook. This is not the case for plt.show() which just gives you a temporary visualization of the graph.